# Optional serializer field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I set a serializer field to optional in Django REST Framework?

I have the following serializer:

```py
class IdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=None)
```

`required` is set to `None` following the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation).

And my view:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PostIdSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            post_id = serializer.validated_data.get("id")
        return Response()
```

**However, when I send a POST request to the endpoint, I get the error:

```json
{
    "id": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

How can I allow no `id` to be sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says `required=False` to have None values, not `required=None`.